# Mongo-hadoop connector API in Spark: Can't update documents

Tags: mongodb, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I try to retrieve the documents in my collection, and to update them with the same values.

I ran this in the spark-shell (with my database and collection already created with one document inside), but I got an exception.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

import org.bson.BSONObject
import com.mongodb.hadoop.{
MongoInputFormat, MongoOutputFormat,
BSONFileInputFormat, BSONFileOutputFormat}

val mongoConfig = new Configuration()
mongoConfig.set("mongo.input.uri",
  "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase.mycollection")

val documents = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(
  mongoConfig,                // Configuration
  classOf[MongoInputFormat],  // InputFormat
  classOf[Object],            // Key type
  classOf[BSONObject])        // Value type

val outputConfig = new Configuration()
outputConfig.set("mongo.output.uri",
  "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase.mycollection")

documents.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
  "file:///this-is-completely-unused",
  classOf[Object],
  classOf[BSONObject],
  classOf[MongoOutputFormat[Object, BSONObject]],
  outputConfig)
```

I got this exception:

```
 ERROR MongoOutputCommitter: Could not write to MongoDB
com.mongodb.BulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server 
localhost:27017. Write errors: [com.mongodb.BulkWriteError@abea0cde].
```

I can't find a way to **update** my documents stored in MongoDB through the `mongo-hadoop` API. I can only create new documents.

Comment: I think maybe the key is already in the mongoDB. So, it can not update the value. Have you solve this problem now?

Answer (score 0):

you need MongoUpdateWritable instead of BsonObject. The following code should work:

```
val updates = documents.mapValues(
      value => new MongoUpdateWritable(
        new BasicDBObject("_id", value.get("_id")),  // Query
        value.asInstanceOf[BasicBSONObject],  // Update operation
        //new BasicDBObject("$set",new BasicDBObject("key","replacedItem")),
        true,  // Upsert
        false,   // Update multiple documents
        true  //replace
      )
    )

    updates.saveAsNewAPIHadoopFile(
      "file:///this-is-completely-unused",
      classOf[Object],
      classOf[MongoUpdateWritable],
      classOf[MongoOutputFormat[Object, MongoUpdateWritable]],
      outputConfig)

  }
```